# Entity Framework column encryption issue

Tags: c#, azure, encryption, entity-framework-5

I'm attempting to use [SecurEntity](https://securentity.codeplex.com/) to implement column encryption for some of the tables in my application.

I am using Dependency Injection to inject a single instance of the DbContext into my all of my repositories.

The DbContext class has an event attached to the SaveChanges event handler which calls the SecurEntity Encrpyt method if the changes being saved saved are on object which should be encrpted.

There is also an event attached to the ObjectMaterialized event handler which decrypts the encrypted objects when they are initially retrieved from the database.

When I debug the application during login, the User object (which is one of the tables which should be encrypted), the User object is retrieved from the Database and decrypted successfully. It then has a few properties such as Last Login date updated and these changes are saved and then encrypted successfully.

**My problem** is that later on in the login process, the User object is retrieved again but it does not fire the ObjectMaterialized event so it is not decrypted.

I assume that this is because a single DbContext is being used due to Dependency Injection and Entity Framework already has an instance of it which is being tracked.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get around this? I am developing an application which will be hosted on Azure so Transparent Data Encryption isn't an option for me and I need to implement some form of encryption.

Comment: Be aware that the current implementation of SecurEntity has a fatal security flaw, which means that the key generated from the certificate is actually never used. For a quick and dirty fix, see https://securentity.codeplex.com/workitem/7376

Answer (score 0):

Web applications should not keep instance of DbContext hanging around. DbContext should live and die during the request (aka get Disposed as soon as request is done with it). Check how is your Dependency Injection configured, you should not under any circumstances have it configured to use DbContext as singleton (single instance for entire application).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Barisa. I am using Ninject and have configured it to use "InRequestScope". I believe this means that the instance is created per HTTP request. Should I avoid this?